# How to identify company/domain with new OAuth2 authentication?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I'm converting an existing Google Apps Marketplace app to support OAuth2.
I understand the use of access keys to identify the user account but how can this be used to link a user to a 'company' or 'domain'?

Our app supports having multiple user logins under one business account - we need to be able to identify what company a user belongs to using OAuth2. How can this be done? (we're using C#).

Is there an additional user API that needs to be called after initial authentication, if so, which one? (we're using C#).